# define time intervals in C

Tags: c, time

I want to define time intervals in C.
For example I want to execute some task every 20 seconds; is the below code correct for this task?

for clarify, our goal in works with time intervals. for example i want to read packets every 20 second and in the end of each interval i want to change some parameters.

```
double blocktime = 20.000000;
clock_t current, next;

current = clock();
    while(trace_read_packet(trace,packet)> 0 ){
        //doing some tasks
        next = clock(); 
        if ((double((next - current) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC))== blocktime) // if it is end of the  interval do some tasks
        {
                          //doing some task
            current = next;

        }
    }//end of while
```

and other questions how i can define loops that works with times?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And just what is a "write code"?

Comment: At first sight your code will probably do more or less what you want (albeit quite inefficiently because it runs around like mad), but using time() instead of clock() will simplify your code a bit.  To make things more efficient we'll need to know more about your target environment and the facilities it offers (threads, ...)

Comment: I don't understand this part of your question: `other questions how i can define loops that works with times?` Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

When you can help it, never use `==` in a case like this. You're setting yourself up for failure. If for some reason code gets delayed and you don't hit it dead on 20, then you're screwed and you'll never do your task.

You should be "assuming a miss" and doing it such as:

```
if ((double((next - current) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC))>= blocktime)
```

---

Yes, taking next-current and dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SEC gives you cpu time used. Note I say *CPU time used* because [`clock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) doesn't report time spend sleeping, so if you use `sleep()` calls in your `//doing some tasks` code, this is not going to be accurate. Otherwise, this code should be close enough to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may make the program eat 100% of cpu time: the program will permanently check if it's time to run `some_task()`.
Why not use sleep():

```
while (1) {
  /* packet handling.. */
  sleep(20);
  some_task();
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to sleep.. i want to read packet for second 1 to second 20 and then when reach at 20 do some task. your seponse sleep 20 second completely and it is not proper!!

Comment: Perhaps with a signal handler for SIGALRM, with an `alarm(20)`, if `trace_read_packet()` is interruptible by signals ?

Comment: i use libtrace for that and i dont think it is interruptible by signal